# sending a visual studio c++ game to a friend who isn't a programmer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation

I have made a game in visual studio and I want to send it to a friend who doesn't have visual studio. (just so that he could play)
I'm using **SFML** in my code but he can download it too if necessary.
There isn't much info about this.
I have tried some stuff but couldn't make it work.

Anyway my project look like this.
(just folders containing png files headers and cpp)

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Search for deploying and packaging.

Comment: VS should allow you to export the thing to a stand-alone .exe. Then you would send that along (together with any external resources it may need like the .png files).

Comment: do you have anything that work on cmake project? all the methods I saw use solution project (the teacher never really thought us what it means)

Comment: Your friend may need to install __Visual C++ Redistributable__ for your version of visual studio.

Comment: Just send `xxx\source\repos\game\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\game\game.exe` to your friend, and click that.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried building the program? Ctrl-F5 should build it into an exe which you can find in your project directory

if you saved it in your repos, then you can find it here:

C:\Users\YOU\source\repos\YOUR GAME\Debug\YOUR GAME.exe

then you can put it on a flash drive and send it to your friend or compress it and send it over email.